# PHP Form with Button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have some experience in JAVA GUI programming and I want to achieve the same in a PHP form.

Situation: I want to have a php form with a submit button. When the button is pressed an ActionEvent should be called to update another part of the form.

How to implement such a feature with HTML,PHP,JAVASCRIPT ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free-coding service, post the code that you're tried and we will try to help. Also, please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need CSS to design.

Comment: @Daan, he needs to learn quite a bit before he can dive into this :/

Comment: `<?php ?><form><button></button></form><?php ?>` now create a function in jquery. This way we cannot help you. Try with some codes. Run it. If you face any problem, put the code here and we could help you. This is the purpose of this platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load latest version of jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<form>
 <button type="button" class="formLoader">Click button</button>
 <div id="formContentToLoad"></div>
</form>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $(".formLoader").click(function(){
    $("#formContentToLoad").load("scriptToRun.php");
  });
});
</script>
```

Whatever markup you need to update in the form, can be put into scriptToRun.php

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myForm").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myForm.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                // todo...
                alert(response);
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Html

```
<form method="POST" class="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="a_field" name="a_field" placeholder="a field" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)) {
    $a_field = $_POST["a_field"];
    // todo..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP and HTML to submit a form try this:
HTML Form

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" />
   <input type="submit" name="sendFormBtn" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["sendFormBtn"]{
    $name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : "Error Response Here";
    //More Validation Here
  }
```